# how to format output of a column in excel to 1.234,56 than 1,234.56 in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel

I am exporting values in my dataset to excel. I want to change the format of all currency value for international users.
For ex - for US - 1,234,567.00 but for Europe - 1.234.567,00.

Please advice how can I achieve this. i am setting DataFormatString in datagrid to set this.

Regards
V.

Comment: I used {0:#.###.###,##} but then too it is not working, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Culture of the user to DE for Europe format and then exported the file. Used {0:n2} column formatting for en-US and de-DE culture and it worked.